# Is This Big O Evaluation Correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm having trouble understanding something. I'm not even sure if it's correct.

In *[Cracking the Code Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984782850)*, there is a section that asks you to determine the Big O for a number of functions. For the most part, they're predictable.

However, one of them throws me for a loop.
Apparently, this evaluates to `O(ab)`:

```
void printUnorderedPairs(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++){
      for (int k = 0; k < 100000; k++){
         System.out.println(arrayA[i] + "," + arrayB[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the rational that

> "100,000 units of work is still constant, so the runtime is *O(ab)*.

I'm trying to see why this could make sense, but I just can't yet; naturally, I expected `O(abc)`.

Yes, `100,000` is a constant and `arrayA` and `arrayB` are arrays, but we're taking the *length* of the arrays.  At the time of running these `for` loops, won't `array[x].length` be a constant (assuming the size of the arrays don't change during their execution)?

So, is the book right? If so, I would really appreciate insight and intuition so I don't fall into the same trap in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time complexity is generally expressed as the number of required elementary operations on an input of size n, where elementary operations are assumed to take a constant amount of time on a given computer and change only by a constant factor when run on a different computer.
```

O(ab) is the complexity in the above case as arrayA and arrayB are of variable length and are fully dependent on the calling function , and 100000 is constant, which won't change by any external factors.

> Complexity is the measure of Unknown

Answer (score 1):

What the authors meant by constant is a value that is a fix, regardless of the input size, unlike the length of input arrays that might change. For instance, the `printUnorderedPairs` might be called with different arrays as parameter, and those arrays might have different sizes among them.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays A and B have an unspecified length, and all you can do is to give an indication of the complexity that is a function of these two lengths. Nothing else is variable in the given code.

Answer (score 1):

The point of Big-O is to examine how the calculation grows as the inputs grow. It's clear that it would double if A doubled, and likewise if B doubled. So linear in those two.

What might be confusing you is that you could easily replace the 100k with C, yet another linear input, but it happens it doesn't have the 100k as a variable, it's a constant.

A similar thing in Big-O problems is where you step through an array a fixed number of times. That doesn't change the Big-O. For example if you step through an array to find the max, that's O(n). Stepping through it twice to find the min and the max is... also O(n). And in fact it's the same as stepping through it once to find the min and max in a single sweep.